# The way of thinking in multiply 2 natural numbers (problem solving”)

Tags: algorithm

> Prove the correctness of the following recursive algorithm to multiply two natural numbers, for all integer constants c ≥ 2.
>
> ```
> function multiply(y,z) comment Return the product yz.
> 1. if z = 0 then return(0) else
> 2. return(multiply(cy, z/c) + y · (z mod c))
> ```

I saw this algorithm in “Algorithm Design Manual”.
I know why it works correctly, but I want to know how this algorithm came to be. Is that a good way to think of multiply two natural number with a constant c?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How to comes up with an algorithm like that, y and z initially in the question , but take into consideration of a constant c in the solution

Comment: profile it in contrast to a program where you simply multiply the two numbers 
 directly.

Comment: How to comes up with an algorithm like that, y and z initially in the question , but take into consideration of a constant c in the solution

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the info. Dont put it as comment.

Comment: This is how you multiply multi-digit numbers with pencil and paper, when c=10

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here. StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  Your question is cognitive psychology and of speculative opinion.  This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(multiply(cy, z/c) + y · (z mod c))

When *c* is the base of your representation (like decimal), then this is how multiplication can be done "manually". It's the ["shift and add" method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Shift_and_add).
In *c*-base *cy* is a single shift of *y* to the left (i.e. adding a zero at the right); and *z/c* is a single shift of *z* to the right: the right most digit is lost.
That lost digit is actually *z mod c*, which is multiplied with *y* separately.

Here is an example with *c = 10*, where the apostrophe signifies the value of variables in a recursive call.
We perform the multiplication with *y* for each separate digit of *z* (retrieved with *z mod c*). Each next product found in this way is written shifted one more place to the left. Usually the 0 is not padded at the right of this shifted product, but it is silently assumed:

```
    354    y
   x 29    z
   ----
   3186    y(z mod c) = 354·9 = 3186
 + 708     y'(z' mod c) = yc(z/c mod c) = 3540·2 = 7080
 ------   
  10266
```

So the algorithm just relies on the mathematical basis for this "shift and add" method in a given *c*-base.